# How to define the Many-to-Many relationship of inner-package model and outer-package model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to define the relationship between the inner-package model and outer-package model?

For example:
When I creating a Laravel package name ArticleManager, which will provide some functions of blog articles CRUD.

Some projects who using our ArticleManager package will establish the many-to-many relationship between User and Article. In Our package, a trait may be useful for User Model:

```
  public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('XXX/Article');
    }
```

But how or where to declare the "Articles belongsToMany Users"? 
We could not write such code in Article Model in our package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a config file :

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(config('article_manager.users.model'));
}
```

With a config file  **config/article_manager** as follow :

```
{
     users:
     {
          model: 'App\User'
     }
}
```